# uninitialized constant Thin::HttpParser (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thin

This is the error I’m getting since I updated Thin from version 1.2.7 to 1.2.8. When I uninstall the newer version and tell my bundle to use 1.2.7 again everything is fine.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.8/lib/thin/request.rb:52:in `initialize': uninitialized constant Thin::HttpParser (NameError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.8/lib/thin/connection.rb:35:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.8/lib/thin/connection.rb:35:in `post_init'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/em/connection.rb:45:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/em/connection.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/em/connection.rb:36:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:1430:in `event_callback'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.8/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.8/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.8/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.8/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `send'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.8/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.8/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.8/bin/thin:6
from /usr/bin/thin:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/thin:19
```

Answer (score 3):

Get 1.2.10

I had the same problem with 1.2.9. The release was broken. 1.2.10 was fixed this afternoon and works like a charm (the developer fixed in minutes!).